# Receive JSON request using JsonValueProviderFactory but without a Type

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using the JsonValueProviderFactory in an MVC2 web app to handle JSON requests inbound from an iOS iPad app.

I don't want to map my JSON to a type.  I just want to receive the raw JSON and pass it on to a model for processing.  What signature should my controller action have to allow me to access the raw JSON being passed to my controller?

Here are the three I've tried so far; none of them work:

```
[ValidateInput(false)] // Allow dodgy chars in the JSON e.g. "<aa>"
        [HttpPost]
        //public ActionResult PushObject(FormCollection form) // no joy
        //public ActionResult PushObject(List<string> parms) // no joy
        //public ActionResult PushObject(string jsonRequest) // no joy
        {...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using a `JsonValueProviderFactory` if you want to get the RAW JSON. The whole point of this factory is to map it to a view model (which by the way is the correct way). If you want to get the Raw stuff you could always read the `Request.InputStream` but that would be absolutely horrible:

```
public ActionResult Do_Not_Do_This_Please_Use_ViewModels_Instead()
{
    Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
    {
        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

you could at least hide this crap in a model binder:

```
public class RawRequestModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object  BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
        request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

and then have a controller action:

```
public ActionResult Do_Not_Do_This_Please_Use_ViewModels_Instead(
    [ModelBinder(typeof(RawRequestModelBinder))] string rawJson
)
{
    ...
}
```

But of course the correct way to do this is to use a view model that will reflect the JSON structure that your iPhone will send:

```
public ActionResult Foo(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: The iPad app is creating the JSON for consumption by the server app.  The JSON format is not known at the time of the server build - it is dynamic.  So, I just want to grab the JSON and pass it to a model that will decipher the JSON.  I just need a simple way to grab the JSON which is being sent by iOS.  Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I don't understand how this model will decipher the JSON if it is dynamic. Also what does *decipher* means? What is this model going to do with the JSON? How does the JSON look like? Could you show a couple of different possibilities for this JSON so that I can get an idea of how *dynamic* it can be?

Comment: I'm using MongoDB.  The JSON will be an arbitrary selection of elements.  The server just needs to persist the JSON to the MongoDB.  It does not care what the JSON looks like.  It is the iOS app that generates the JSON.

Comment: Alright, I see. You could always use the following JSON then: `{"json":"here you could put your arbitrary json"}` and have a view model with a single string property called `Json` and leave the json value provider factory do the job.

Comment: I guess I could wrap the json in an outer json element, but that seems a tad unnecessary given that the inner json is totally dynamic.  Thanks again.

Comment: Well then I guess you could read the Request.InputStream. But get rid of the JsonValueProviderFactory as it serves for nothing in your scenario.